# In openCV, using HOGDescriptor's setSVMDetector functionality with an input array

Tags: android, opencv

I am having some trouble with the HOGDescriptor.setSVMDetector functionality in OpenCV4Android.

Android requires a passed Mat() for the `HOGDescriptor.setSVMDetector()` method. Note that this differs from the C++ specification, where the function is declared as `setSVMDetector(const vector<float>& detector)`. The question is how to input a linear SVM model in - that is, how do you turn an array of floating point values into an OpenCV4Android Mat such that a HOGDescriptor object will accept it as input to the setSVMDetector method?

I have tried analyzing the output of `HOGDescriptor.getDefaultPeopleDetector()`. This gives a Mat with 3781 rows, 1 column, and type CV_32F. When recreating this, and for that matter when trying any variation (e.g. transposition, 1x1 Mat with a single array entry, etc), the output is:

```
error: checkDetectorSize() in function virtual void cv::HOGDescriptor::setSVMDetector(cv::InputArray)
```

Any advice on how to set up an SVM detector this way in Android would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: Can you create an empty mat with 3781 rows and 1 column type float and copy each of your array elements to it? If that works for setSVM you can probably link the array to your mat without copying, too

Comment: Hi there, I have tried making a new Mat() and populating it with our floating-point array data. The other strategies mentioned - transposition, etc - were all attempts I made to vary the format. In all of those cases, this checkDetectorSize() assertion error came up.

Comment: what if you use `.getDefaultPeopleDetector` , create a new empty mat, copy each element of people detector to an array and from there to your new mat (element-wise like you would copy from your array) and use that? does it work? Idea is to find out whether your fault is erroneous svm detector data/values or just the format you provide, so with getDefault... you definitely have some legal svm data, now form a manual Mat and use the legal svm data to create the right format manually.

Comment: Awesome, good thinking with this approach! With the proper SVM data from `getDefaultPeopleDetector` it actually worked fine, so the issue must be with our floating point array. Any idea what that checkDetectorSize issue might be in that case?

Comment: sorry, I have nearly no experience with selftrained svm data, maybe someone else knows something about that (maybe open new question with appropriate title and close this one if the title/text doesnt fit anymore).